# Instrumental variable regression with endogenous ratio variable

Tags: time-series, econometrics, instrumental-variables, ratio

I want to estimate the following regression:

$y_t=a+bx_t+e_t$

where $x_t$ is an endogenous ratio variable, i.e., continuous values bound between 0 and 1 and $y_t$ is a continuous variable.

I want to instrument for $x_t$ using $z_t$. The first stage regression will take the form:

$x_t=a+bz_t+e_t$

As $x_t$ is a ratio variable, are there issues estimating the first stage with OLS as the predicted values could plausibly be <0 or >1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We implement Instrumental Variables estimation to obtain asymptotic consistency, paying the price of higher estimator variance.
The issue you mention does not affect asymptotic consistency -it still obtains.

As regards its effect on small-sample behavior, it cannot be explicitly quantified separately from the estimation error from the first-stage regression.

Since you still obtain consistency, I believe you can proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would the same be true if $x_t$ was a dummy variable, as opposed to a ratio variable?